# Teradata: Recursively Subtract

Tags: sql, recursion, teradata, recursive-query

I have a set of data as follows:

```
Product  Customer  Sequence   Amount
A        123       1          928.69
A        123       2          5032.81
A        123       3          6499.19
A        123       4          7908.57
```

What I want to do is recursively subtract the amounts based on the result of the previous subtraction (keeping the first amount as-is), into in a 'Result' column

e.g. Subtract 0 from 928.69 = 928.69, subtract 928.69 from 5032.81 = 4104.12, subtract 4104.12 from 6499.19 = 2395.07, etc (for each product/customer)

The results I'm trying to achieve are:

```
Product  Customer  Sequence  Amount    Result
A        123       1         928.69    928.69
A        123       2         5032.81   4104.12
A        123       3         6499.19   2395.07
A        123       4         7908.57   5513.50
```

I had been trying to achieve this using combinations of LEAD & LAG, but couldn't figure out how to use the result in the next row.

I'm thinking it's possible using a recursive statement, iterating over the sequence, however I'm not familiar with teradata recursion and couldn't successfully adapt the samples I found.

Can anyone please direct me on how to format a recursive teradata SQL statement to achieve the above result? I'm also open to non-recursive options if there are any.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MY_TEST (Product CHAR(1), Customer INTEGER, Sequence INTEGER, Amount DECIMAL(16,2)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES ('A', 123, 1, 928.69);
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES ('A', 123, 2, 5032.81);
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES ('A', 123, 3, 6499.19);
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES ('A', 123, 4, 7908.57);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really weird because of the alternation of the + and -.

If you know the value is always positive, then this works:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as customer, 928.69 as amount,  928.69 as result union all
      select 2, 5032.81, 4104.12 union all
      select 3, 6499.19, 2395.07 union all
      select 4, 7908.57, 5513.50 
    )
select t.*,
       abs(sum( case when seqnum mod 2 = 1 then - amount else amount end ) over (partition by product order by sequence rows unbounded preceding)
from t;
```

The `abs()` is really a shortcut.  If the resulting value could be negative, you can have an outer `case` expression to determine if the result should be multiplied by -1 or 1:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when sequence mod 2 = 1 then -1 else 1 end) *
        sum( case when sequence mod 2 = 1 then - amount else amount end ) over (partition by product order by sequence  rows unbounded preceding)
       )
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select colA-der_col_A from table A,
(select coalesce(min(col_A) as der_col_A over (partition by col_B  order by col_A rows between 1 following and 1 following), 0)
from table) B
on (A.col_b=B.Col_B);
```

Replace col_A and col_B with your key columns.Product,customer and sequence in your case.